# how can I link two files in two separate directories so that Makefile compiles them?

Tags: makefile

I have two files

1. test-subseq.c
2. maxSeq.c

They are in two separate directories

1. ~/learn2prog/15_tests_subseq
2. ~/learn2prog/16_subseq

How do I get my Makefile in /16_subseq to compile test-subseq.c and maxSeq.c together? currently I have this in my Makefile:

[image: current Makefile image]

Sorry, I'm really new to programming and this is all in C.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In future, please post the relevant code in your question; not an image, not a link to anything, but the actual text. (I'd edit your question to correct this, but what you put up is a screenshot, so I couldn't just copy-paste, I'd have to type it all in, not to mention the strain of reading indigo-on-black, which is also why I'm reluctant to try to answer this question. See the problem?)

Answer (score 0):

Make supports relative paths.

From a project organization perspective it might make sense to put your Makefile into the learn2prog folder.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can do anything with Make, you must know how to do it *without* Make.

You start with two source files:

```
test-subseq.c
maxSeq.c
```

You compile them, to produce two object files:

```
gcc -c test-subseq.c
gcc -c maxSeq.c
```

Then you link the two object files to produce an executable:

```
gcc -o myMaxSeq test-subseq.o maxSeq.o
```

Ah, but you're working in `~/learn2prog/16_subseq/`, and one of your sources is not here, it's in `~/learn2prog/15_tests_subseq/`, so that compiling step won't work; the compiler will complain that it can't find the source.

No problem, you can do this:

```
gcc -c ~/learn2prog/15_tests_subseq/test-subseq.c
```

or this:

```
gcc -c ../15_tests_subseq/test-subseq.c
```

And *after you verify that this works,* you can modify your Make rule:

```
test-subseq.o: ../15_tests_subseq/test-subseq.c
    gcc -c ../15_tests_subseq/test-subseq.c
```

And when you're ready, you can try the advanced trick of using an automatic variable, to make the rule tidier:

```
test-subseq.o: ../15_tests_subseq/test-subseq.c
    gcc -c $<
```

Further refinements are possible, but that should be enough for now.